# I am using NSwag in my api and it generates a file. In this file I get a datetimeoffset but I wanted a datetime

Tags: c#, blazor

the generated file:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("measurementTimeStamp", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.DateTimeOffset MeasurementTimeStamp { get; set; }
```

The API response:

```
public class Response {
public DateTime MeasurementTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Expected:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("measurementTimeStamp", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public System.DateTime MeasurementTimeStamp { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a repsonse that give a json file with that json i genarate a file in this file i get back an datetimeoffset and not an datetime is there anyway to change an setting to get this